# Why fopen gets fail in native method due to permission issue from Android-NDK application?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

see i have following code in one native call

```
errno = 0;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("jigar.txt","wb");
if(fp == NULL)
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APPNAME, "FOPEN FAIL with %d",errno);
else
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APPNAME, "FOPEN pass ");
```

which gets fail and shows

```
FOPEN FAIL with 30
```

now here 30 means it shows error

```
#define EROFS       30  /* Read-only file system */
```

In MainFest file on my application i have added this line

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
```

still i am getting this error..

How to resolve this issue?

---

**Edit**

thanks by specifies folder name it works But

In my case i have one Library which has such fopen() call where file names i can not give. It takes it default filename.

And i am using this Library in my ndk application so in this case how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yuppi finally i got that

i have did this way

first change the current directory of my process from `"/"` to `"/sdcard/"`

```
chdir("/sdcard/");
```

and then it find path with respect to /sdcard/

and everything WORKING..!!!

Comment: Yaa this is a good solution too.. But changing a directory may create problem if your library is doing some more operations on the local files by assuming their existence. What you can do is read the current directory location. Store it in a string, do chdir, perform the operation and do chdir to old location once agin. This should not creat a problem ideally.. All the best

Comment: yea i thought that this is not the ethical way to change the current directory but thanks for suggestion after doing my work i will change the current directory back to its original value..!!

Answer (score 1):

By default when you are running your App, it runs in its own context. fopen("jigar.txt","wb"); will try to open the file in current directory, which i think mostly would be /data/.. So you cant create files like that. Instead, if you want a folder inside /data/ you can call a function gteDir() and inside it you can create your own files. Ok this is all for general information.

Coming to your problem, as mentioned above you need to give absolute path to create a file in a different directory. This is the same case even in Linux.

For the Library thing, you can do two things.

1) Make changes in the library source code and compile it again using NDK. While making changes, give some string as the argument for fopen() which you will pass it while executing the Application.

2) [remount](http://android-tricks.blogspot.in/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html) the filesystem in which your library is creating the file, then do chmod 777 to the specific directory inside which your file is being created. Now execute the Application. It should work. But this is not generic. If you are doing it for some testing purpose then this solution is simplest and time saving...

If stuck somewhere, let me know..

Comment: hey thanks buddy we have solved problem almost at same time..!!! your both suggestion are right but my work done without that see my answer and yes by default current directory path is not "/data/" but its "/" as per my understanding.!!!

Comment: Nice tht problem got solved.. check the comment i posted on your solution. Just tke care of that rest i whink everything is fine... Anyway congrats on solving your own problem .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify folder where to write the "jigar.txt" file. Like this:

```
fp = fopen("/sdcard/figar.txt", "wb");
```